# Docker 2 commands execution with mounted directory

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm starting to learn docker. I only dont understand one thing. Is it possible that docker executes 2 commands?

My docker container takes files from my volume and starts my app. Is it possible that my containers will mount a directory and after that execute npm install and at the end it executes my script?

Right now is so that I need to have all node modules in my mouned directory. It means my solution makes no sense. If anybody clone git repository there is no node_modules. I wish that all node modules will be installed in my container :(

my docker file:

```
FROM node:slim

RUN npm install -g nodemon@1.14.7
COPY package.json /skill/package.json


WORKDIR /skill/
RUN npm install
WORKDIR /skill/dist/app/

EXPOSE 8000
EXPOSE 27017

ENTRYPOINT ["nodemon"]
```

My docker command:

```
sudo docker run -v /home/alexa/Desktop/Template/Alexa_universal_skill_template:/skill -it --network myNetwork --name alexa alexa
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write a bash script that runs your initialization, similar to this one:

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /skill/dist/app/
npm install
nodemon
```

Let's call it `entrypoint.sh`

Then, edit your Dockerfile to look like this:

```
FROM node:slim

RUN npm install -g nodemon@1.14.7
COPY package.json /skill/package.json

WORKDIR /skill/
RUN npm install
WORKDIR /skill/dist/app/

EXPOSE 8000
EXPOSE 27017

COPY entrypoint.sh /
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your want to distribute your image including your app you have to build and tag your docker image and than push it to a registry.

```sh
# dont miss the dot on the end, or the name of the directory of your app
docker build -f Dockerfile -t mynodeapp:latest .

# after the above command, you'll get an image with a new tag and your commands executed

# use the following commands to push an image to a registry    
docker tag mynodeapp:latest registry/mynodeapp:latest
docker push registry/mynodeapp:latest
```